# Continuous UDP inquiry in Python stops randomly

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm rather new to Python and working on a small script for UDP inquiries to a network camera on a given port. I'm sending the inquiry string and expect to receive a string with the needed information. I got the basic functionality running with the code shown below and am receiving the expected response. However, I need the inquiry to be done continuously and in best case roughly according to common camera framerates (25fps). My script works for this case as well, but after some time just stops after sending one last inquiry which never gets answered. The timespan after which this stop happens might be a few hundreds inquiries or just less than

So far I have some difficulties wrapping my head around all the functions of sockets, so I'm not sure where to start looking for my problem. I was hoping that socket.SO_REUSEADDR might be part of an solution but so far this didn't work out. My first guess was that I might just be flooding the camera with too many requests but the issue still comes up with a longer sleep time after each message. Also the inquiry works fine when sent continuously with a tool like Packetsender, so the issue seems to be with my script.

I would be grateful for any hint in which direction I should be looking for a solution.

```
import socket
import time

UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.17.25"
UDP_PORT_NO = 52381
Message = b'\x01\x10\x00\x05\xff\xff\xff\xff\x81\x09\x06\x12\xff'

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
clientSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
clientSock.connect((UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))

while True:
     clientSock.send(Message)
     reply = clientSock.recv(1024)
     reply_hex = reply.hex()
     print(reply_hex)

     time.sleep(0.04)
```

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller buffer size?

Comment: Yes,  I went down to 32, still losing it after a while.

Comment: Why the sleep? The camera will respond in its own good time. And why the `SO_REUSEADDR`? You aren't reusing any port numbers here.

Comment: My thought was that a 0.04s sleep would give me the 25 inquiries per second I want. And the idea behind SO_REUSEADDR I can't really explain by now, it seemed to make sense in the beginning because I thought it might help with the script somehow getting stuck.

Comment: `SO_REUSEADDR` is generally used if the specific port is being used by another process but you still wanna go ahead and connect. It usually happens that you open a socket and do not close it. Next time you try and run the same code, you get an error that socket is already in use. `SO_REUSEADDR` flag helps prevent that.

Comment: Okay, got that, thanks. `SO_REUSEADDR` is useless here but does no harm either, I guess?

Comment: @DeepakGouda He isn't binding to a specific port. It serves no useful purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem by adding `clientSock.settimeout(0.1)` and putting `reply = clientSock.recv(32)` into a try block.